# Custom Status "Downloadable products"

Tags: magento2, downloadable

Magento 2.4.5-p1 here.

Problem: I want to have a downloadable product status that is different from "Complete" when completed.

[image]

So far I have set, that status is "Pending" to download but also limited to only immediate payments. So order will remain in "Pending" status max. 1 minute as immediately paid and Status switches to "Complete" after that (via Mollie). Good for clients, they can buy and immediately download product (I do not use invoice function via Magento but via ERP).

However, my ERP system cannot pick up those orders of Downloadable products, which are "Complete". It can pickup status "Pending" and "Processing" and I could add a custom status for pick up, but not status complete. And status to "Compelete" switches to quick for Downloadable products, thus I am not able to get all those orders into my ERP system.

Is there any way to add a custom status for paid, completed downloadable product orders? Like "DL-paid"? Does anyone know how and where this could be achieved?

Thank you in advance